# LTSP problem with old CPU client

Tags: ltsp

I want to setup LTSP with 12.04, but I have a problem with some clients. When I try to boot them, fail with a reference to cmov and cx8 support in the CPU.

After some investigation, I discover that Ubuntu dropped support on non i686 CPU since 10.10.

So I'm needing a ltsp client 10.04 or older. When I issue the command:

ltsp-build-client --dist lucid --arch i386

it fails when start processing "/var/cache/apt/archives/ltsp-client-core_5.2.1-0ubuntu9_i386.deb"

If I try to process this package alone inside the chroot it gives more info, something like "ltsp-client cannot be installed in a regular machine" ...

It seems to me a bug in ltsp-build-client process of building the client ...

Anyone with the same problem?

Any help?

Ideas?

Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

you need to use / compile a custom kernel or use another distribution that support your processor.

"i386" is now in fact i686 with PAE enabled hardware. I've had that with via C3 processors.

For the easy part use xubuntu or lubuntu instead of ubuntu.

if you don't want lxde or xfce you'll be able to install kde, gnome, gnome shell or unity afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

I am having same config.
If you are not ready to buy higher thin clients for next 1 year, then

Don't hesitate to install Ubuntu 10.04 freshly, and then do install `ltsp-standalone-server` on desktop, follow steps by ltsp docs.

You are done with it.
Nothing is complicated.
Just make sure that you won't upgrade linux 2.35 to higher versions.